# Is there a Github Actions warning state?

Tags: github, github-actions

Besides success and failed, is there any warning state for Github Actions? How to set one for an action that is not owned by me? E.g. Github Actions return code 1 (error), in this case I only want this to be considered as warning, not as error.

Comment: Hey. Did you find the answer to this?

Comment: No ): 10 more characters to go ;-)

Comment: It looks like this feature doesn't exist; here's a github community feature request for this which is probably the best way to engage github on this: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/11592

Answer (score 6):

The closest I could find is this:

`echo "::warning file=app.py,line=10,col=5::Code formatting issues detected"`

It creates an annotation in the job summary, but the Job & Step themselves are still marked as fully green.

[image]